# SharePoint list filter view with item level permissions

Tags: 2010, list

In one of our SharePoint List items are grouped by code folder, let say user selects in the InfoPath code 123 item is moved under folder 123. Each folder has unique permissions groups added.

Client has a requirement where they want reports as they call when a user selects a date range they can see aggregate of X column value for all the records, but the items have unique permissions set. Currently when user selects date range they only view aggregate of X column related to their agency or items they have permission on. Any idea if it is possible to display aggregate value of all items of X column for a user.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

Alternatives? Development of custom webpart where you can run code with elevated privileges and 'see' all items. You can then do aggregate on all items and display only final result.
This custom webpart can be quite simple to develop (depending on your exact needs) but still it is custom and you need to develop it. Anyway, there is no other (OOTB) way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can I develop sandbox solution? I don't have permissions to deploy farm base solution.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Sandbox solutions always run in context of current user. `Methods in a sandboxed solution cannot be configured to run with the elevated privileges of the user identity in which the application pool runs.` [Restrictions on Sandboxed Solutions - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615454.ASPx#BKMK_ThinAssembly)